# Set declaration and use in where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL statement that has multiple case statements like the below:

```
SUM(CASE [Type]
    WHEN 418
    THEN CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed
    AND( PMTS.Amount >0 OR PMTS.Mileage >0)
    AND PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0 THEN Mileage END
    ELSE 0 END) AS DriverMileage
```

But I need the result of the sum to set a variable and use that in the where in the WHERE clause.

Example below

```
DECLARE @contribution decimal
SElECT PMTS.VolunteerId ,
SET @contribution = SUM(CASE [Type]
              WHEN 1003
              THEN CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed
      AND( PMTS.Amount >0 OR PMTS.Mileage >0)
              AND PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0
              THEN Amount END
              ELSE 0 END) AS GPContributions
FROM PMTS WHERE @contribution >0
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need a variable here, also please confirm the "case when" syntax used. Here is a sample query:

```
select * from 
(SElECT PMTS.VolunteerId ,SUM(CASE [Type]
              WHEN 1003
              THEN CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed
      AND( PMTS.Amount >0 OR PMTS.Mileage >0)
              AND PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0
              THEN Amount END
              ELSE 0 END) AS GPContributions
FROM PMTS)as A WHERE GPContributions >0
```

Comment: Cheers thanks - looking for the more complicated approach when a simpler was need :)